# API's De Requisições Com Banco De Dados Para AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, banco-de-dados, api, request

Quais as API's para fazer requisições com banco de dados(de preferencia mysql) que eu tenho disponíveis para trabalhar integrado com o AngularJS, alguma que seja mais simples de se usar e que rode em qualquer servidor, eu ia usar o nodeJS mas os servidores pra rodar ele são mais caros e eu não tenho condições de arcar com isso no momento...

Lembrando que sou um desenvolvedor iniciante e minha linguagem base é o PHP

Comment: Você pode construir sua API em **PHP** mesmo, e só na hora de devolver as transações do banco de dados fazer um **parse** para **JSON** e consumir os dados em Json no angular.

Comment: Como assim api pra conectar no banco de dados e você não quer fazer isso no servidor? `Angularjs` roda no cliente, no navegador, não tem uma api pra você conectar em um banco de dados remoto, você precisa escrever um código servidor pra fazer isso. Se você usar `php`, escreva um código nessa linguagem que acesse o banco de dados e depois execute esse código a partir de uma chamada `ajax` do `angularjs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você poderia utilizar qualquer API que quisesse para trabalhar com AngularJS, não faz diferença nenhuma qual tecnologia você utilizará no lado do servidor pois no fim das contas é um WebService que transmite só dados (no formato JSON preferencialmente).

Visto que você já tem experiência com php e é um desenvolvedor iniciante, existem algumas tecnologias que cairiam bem, pela simplicidade e facilidade de lidar, no entanto não há como fugir de compreender o funcionamento de aplicações web e algumas ferramentas que são utilizadas nessas aplicações.

Portanto, para facilitar todo o trabalho, você precisaria de um [micro-framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microframework) (uma versão mais simplificada ou minimalista de um framework web) e uma [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) para php. Felizmente, nisso temos uma diversidade grande de frameworks e ORMs gratuitos e open source, então não será difícil escolher um.

Eu particularmente recomendo o conjunto oferecido pelo [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), que é o micro-framework [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) em conjunto com a ORM [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent). No entanto, diversos frameworks também oferecem suporte a essa combinação como por exemplo, [Phalconphp](http://phalconphp.com/) e [Fuelphp](http://fuelphp.com/), e [outros](https://xbu.me/a-comparison-of-php-micro-frameworks/) que oferecem essas ferramentas isoladamente como [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) para micro aplicações e o [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) como ORM.

No fim das contas, acaba por ser uma questão opinativa, cada um deve escolher o framework que melhor serve as suas necessidades e conveniências. Mas por exemplo, se você utilizar o Lumen com o Eloquent, a sua aplicação assumir um design muito mais limpo e intuitivo do que em puro php.